# Prevent control's Size-property to be set?

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, user-controls, overriding

I'm trying to create a custom `Panel` class which wouldn't allow it's size to be set outside of the class.
What I tried was this:

```
public class FixedPanel : Panel
{
    public override Size Size { get; private set; }
}
```

But I get an error saying that `FixedPanel.Size.set: cannot override inherited member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Size.set' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override`

Is there a way to prevent user from setting control's Size?

---

**Edit:** I came up with a cleaner solution that removes the need to set two properties separately, but I'm not sure if it's really a proper way either.
Here's what I'd do:

```
private Size fixedSize;
private void SetFixedSize(Size size=null)
{
    if (size)
        this.fixedSize = size;

    if (this.Size != this.fixedSize)
        this.Size = this.fixedSize;
}

public FixedPanel()
{
    this.SizeChanged += SetFixedSize;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with new:

```
public class FixedPanel : Panel
{
    public new Size Size { get; private set; }
}
```